# Few database in one dbml?

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm creating application that must use few databases. Is there any ways to handle different databases in one `.dbml` file or I should use one `.dbml` file per one database?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/linqToSql5.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only one database per dbml file, the context expects a single connection string.

Comment: LINQ doesn't belong to some specific language, why should I tag this with c#?